# Thinkpad P51 battery life 2.5 hours

Tags: nvidia, battery, thinkpad

I posted here an issue with my Thinkpad P51:
https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-P-and-W-Series-Mobile/Thinkpad-P51-battery-just-2-5-hours/m-p/4404927

Battery life is just 2.5 hours, but should be around 8 hours as Lenovo state.

Someone on lenovo forum suggest to disable nVidia, as I am using Intel gaphic (see last response).

Basically he suggest:

"If You turn off nVidia card in BIOS everyhing will look the same if You have configured everything (drivers etc) to use Intel graphic. No matter which display You have."

My question is: can this help and if yes, how to do this? Because as I remember I just install Intel graphic.

Thanks

Comment: you're using the Nouveau graphics driver. it's a battery hog. if you want to save battery do what windows does and use the correct graphical driver, in this case nvidia. to answer your question yes it can help to disble the graphic card completely from BIOS but I see it as a bit of a shame to not use the nvidia card at all. you might want to play games or do other graphically intensive things. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BtDkczrf5fI

Comment: @tatsu I don't need to play game, it's just for work stuff. I want that my battery have long time, not just 2.5 hours. But I don't want also lose something else by doing this, like for example my screen is 4K. I use for web design, and so. I think that now Intel it's used, and not nvidia. And now all is fine. By disabling nvidia, which I think I don't use, would the things be the same? and just battery better?

Comment: well I really think for 4K you'll be better served with nvidia rather than intel. I'm not sure how good intel is with 4k video (youtube) for example. you can try it as it stands when you have nvidia driver installed you can switch between nvidia and intel follow this guide : https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-card-ubuntu . I suggest you test out daily usage with intel then nvidia. and then once you know which one you want definitively we can apply a permanent battery saving solution. :)

Comment: Thank You! I will follow that tutorial also how to install nvidia and will try to switch, and let you know.