# Can't login after enable nvidia driver

Tags: nvidia, uefi, secure-boot

I posted here a question regarding battery issue with Thinkpad:
[Thinkpad P51 battery life 2.5 hours](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133223/thinkpad-p51-battery-life-2-5-hours)

I have followed the tutorial https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-card-ubuntu for switch to nvidia since was suggested.

After enabling nvidia it asked for set a password for enable UEFI secure boot. I set a password and after reboot I click "MOK enroll" and before I finish to enter password the system load ubuntu.

Now when I try to login on ubuntu, it said "Failed to start session".

I think that because I didn't add full password when it asked MOK enroll...

How to fix this as I can't now even login on Thinkpad (for this reason I am posting with this account).

Any help is much appreciated as now I stuck  :(

Comment: I was able to login in terminal using CTRL-ALT-F1 but not sure now how to reset the MOK / Secure Boot so that I can login normally

Comment: Not sure if disable secure boot will help, as explained here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS

Comment: I am trying method 2, disable-validation, but after `mokutil --disable-validation`it ask me password and after adding password appear error message "Failed to request new MokSB state"

Comment: I disable secure boot using mkutil (adding sudo this time) and worked, but I am still not able to login, Failed to start session still appear ... Please help me

Comment: I disable Secure boot in BIOS, but still the same, can't login , failed to start session :(

Comment: I will try this sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop , as suggested by someone ?

Comment: sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop this don't work as there are other dependency required... seem like I need to re-install 18.04 :(